# generating password with crypt (32-bits vs 64-bit)

Tags: php, security, salt, crypt

I'm using this function to generate a password:

```
function generarPassword($password, $cost=11){
    $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
    $salt='$'.implode('$',array("2y",str_pad($cost,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT),$salt));
    return crypt($password,$salt);
}
```

My problem is that when I use it on a 64-bit server, the result is this:

```
$2y$11$1ws6drmcqHCWG8wj5bm5s.R8Opc0.JEjXy0.P9UsHjqoxjZQ5GYLW
```

And when I use it on a 32-bit server, the result is this:

```
$2uUq69/OVG3M
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Why is that happening? the `$salt` is the same length in both
2. Is there any security problem with the 32-bit password?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on PHP 5.5+? If so, `password_hash()` will take care of applying the appropriate rounds/etc. and you do not need to manage the salt independently (which is probably causing your problem).

Answer (score 5):

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$",
>   "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters
>   from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this
>   range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string
>
> PHP before 5.3.7 only support "$2a$" as the salt prefix: PHP 5.3.7

Your `$salt` does not meet the `22 characters from the alphabet` constraint of the blowfish algorithm.  You need to review your processes on generating a proper salt.

```
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
echo $salt.' ('.strlen($salt).')';
// example: D3Zc0fv8BBLKYnpH0iSV0w== (24)
```

Secondly, you are using a prefix `$2y$` which is only supported after PHP 5.3.7.  Both of these are concerns you need to address if you're using this code on two different systems.

Comment: The length should be correct, if you trimmed the padding "=" at the end. The real question is why does it work on the 64-bit server? Are both versions of PHP the same?

Comment: @JayDansand, yes, if he trims those characters which I don't see anywhere  in the code where that happens.  I'm guessing urandom isn't returning the same on both systems.  The function(s) chosen are not great ones for generating a blowfish salt.

Comment: Agreed. `mcrypt_create_iv()` with MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM will not have guaranteed good entropy even on Linux servers (it doesn't block if the entropy pool is small), and on Windows it wouldn't be supported on PHP < 5.3. `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` would be better in all cases (except the Windows bug on old PHP versions). Not that it really matters, but additionally 22 random characters from the 2^6 alphabet specified would be 132 bits of entropy, compared with the 128 bits provided by 16 random bytes.

Comment: Right, the server is 32-bit and has PHP5.1.6... maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Is there any function you recommend me to implement so the generated password are still secure, and work in old servers/php and new ones?

Comment: @sebastianbarria 5.1 is very old.  I never said you couldn't use crypt, I just said you weren't following the guidelines on the [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) manual.   You need to only use alphanumerical characters in the salt with the `2a` prefix.

Comment: @sebastianbarria - PHP before 5.3 could not calculate BCrypt hashes, and updating your server is absolutely the best option. If you are stick with 5.1, the [phpass library](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) may be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @martinstoeckli... But what if I just leave that short hash in my DB (the short-one generated in 32-bit systems)?... Is that insecure?

Comment: @sebastianbarria - To me it looks like crypt has fallen back to the DES hash algorithm, and took the '$2' as salt. This would mean that there is nearly zero protection for your passwords, an attacker can brute-force with more than 10 Giga DES / second and the hashes are unsalted. You could use a scheme like in this [answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/103393/8343) together with the phpass library (instead of BCrypt), but really consider to update the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot @martinstoeckli, I'll give it a try